# What is the out-of-universe reason Bumblebee lost his voice in Fall of Cybertron?

Tags: video-games, transformers

What is the out-of-universe reason Bumblebee lost his voice in *Fall of Cybertron*? (It's his starting state: not an event that occurs mid-story.)

I was originally curious what the in-universe reason was, but that's apparently answered already [here on TFormers.com](https://tformers.com/transformers-want-to-know-how-bumblebee-loses-his-voice-the-story-has-finally-been-told/13749/news.html).

Now I'm curious why this was decided upon out-of-universe.

The cynic in me thinks this was to align the *War for*/*Fall of Cybertron* universe with the <strike>loathsome</strike> Bayverse. I'm tempted to go on a rant on how unnecessary and detrimental that was to an otherwise well-done, loving homage to the *G1 Transformers*, but I'll stop myself short.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by an out of universe reason... If there is an in universe reason for it to happen then out of universe they have to "make it so" to align with the story being told. Maybe I'm not seeing the question correctly here, but it seems obvious to me...

Comment: @Odin1806 It seems like they are operating on the assumption that the in-universe reason was actually only added due to out-of-universe interests.  I don't know if there's enough evidence of that happening to justify the question; but that's how I understand the motivation.

Comment: @Odin1806 - _War for Cybertron_ was stylistically an homage to the _G1 Transformers_ - so the characters were visually reminiscent of the 80s cartoon characters, and their voices and personalities were similarly aligned. Nowhere in that (cartoon) continuity has Bumblebee been without a voice. However, voiceless Bumblebee is a defining characteristic of the bayverse _Transformers_. So my question is _why was this bayverse trait grafted into what was otherwise perceived to be a G1 homage?_ I believe the in-universe reason follows an out-of-universe decision - not the other way around.

Comment: @StoneThrow - Gotcha, I see your reasoning now. I remember playing both of those games, but not enough to remember that Bee did not have a voice... I thought there was a scene or two that he did, but I could be remembering only the scenes from War... either way I am too far removed from them now to be of help to you... good luck...

Comment: @Odin1806 - You're right about Bee having a voice in _War_. In fact, he had his voice all the way through that game. I just recently started _Fall_, and as I noted, he's already voiceless at the start of the game. There's a throwaway line from Ratchet when he's evaluating Bee after the hit he took in the intro cutscene: "_...voice chip still broken, but that's nothing new_" To me, making Bee voiceless feels like an awkward and unnatural grafting of bayverse Bee into G1-homage-verse Bee. But I promised to not let myself rant. :)

Comment: A while ago I watched a documentary or episode of something that explained all about the behind the scenes interactions between Hasbro, High Moon Studios and the Michael Bay movies that probably contributed to these kind of design choices, I'll see if I can remember what or where it was. High Moon Studios also created the Dark Side of the Moon tie-in game in between War and Fall which could be related to this decision.